# Securing and authenticating + authorizing REST API calls in Java EE

Tags: authentication, rest, jakarta-ee, authorization

I have separate WARs in different app servers for server side and client side. The UI interaction with server side is through REST APIs.

Now the problem is the REST service is hosted on 8080 port and i see that if i just give the URL i can see the result XML. Now this is dangerous. I do not want anyone, other than the request originating from my client side WAR to actually see the result. Client side authentication and authorization is there, but how do i propagate the same to the server side WAR. Just to explain the workflow,let me give a sample use case: 1. the user requests that he needs to see all his orders. Now the userid and sent in the post request and the appropriate REST API is invoked and it returns all the orders for that userrid. Now my worry is anyone in knowledge of that URL can actually get list of all the orders for any user. How do i stop this un-authorized and possibly un-authenticated requests? How best i can integrate authorization and authentication in this scenario of two different WARs for client and server side that are deployed in different containers.

Comment: you want like - if user have credential than he/she can get data, but you want to restrict URI from unauthorized user. ?

Comment: well, basically i want to ensure that the server side request is correctly authenticated and authorized. How does AWS ensure this...they are built on Rest APIs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate Token when user logs in
save at server side as well as set at client side in cookie

now when any request foes to server
token cookie goes with that request automatically
and you can get that cookie at server side in `@CookieParam`
so you can validate easily that user is authenticated os not.

Comment: NOt sure if this is a great way to do it. probably adding and encrypted authenticated object on https could do the trick. what u say?

Comment: i think https could not do any trick (Use Two ServletAdaptor Named "Secure" an "Rest" on Secure write one servlet and in servlet first  do authentication if everything is fine than redirect to "Rest" otherwise send 404...

Comment: hmm...makes sense. but how do i authenticate. I mean based on what. What should i pass from my UI layer to the rest api so that it can authenticate and authorize that request. Also, i do not want to send that 'imp' request parameter in simple text right?

Comment: whichis written on my answer token send through header(goes by default in Cookie of Request Header, you can get that value form Rest service by @CookieParam and in Servlet Request.getCookies();